# How to disable trailing slash appending?

Tags: php, apache

I'm writing my own site on PHP, MVC, and it uses routing (everything redirects to /index.php).

Structure of the site is something like this:

```
/module/
/module/catalog/
/module/catalog/entry.html
```

Also I have real folders named /module/catalog/ in my site's root.

I need MVC to load content only when the user has requested URL with trailing slash, otherwise MVC must throw 404 error. 
**But** when I follow url like /module/catalog , and there is a real directory with such address, Apache automatically appends trailing slash, and MVC continues working, not giving a 404 error (as it should be).
If there is no such directory, URL stays without slash and I see 404 (this is ok).

How to disable appending slash in first case? I want to process URL's with and without slash differently, using PHP script.

**DirectorySlash Off in the root .htaccess has absolutely no effect**. Here is my /.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301]

DirectorySlash Off

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/errors\/
# TODO: Remove PHP gere - it's only for testing!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt|ico|php)$
# QSA says to overwrite GET values defined in target address string.
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: don't do that on your own, check laravel or symfony

Answer (score 1):

First, let me start by saying it's probably not a great idea to have folders that reflect your URL re-writes in the first place.

Other MVCs put index files in their class directories which are just HTML pages that look like 404 pages. This way if the user DOES request it with the slash they are redirected to the index.html page which displays the 404 text.

Check out the "index.html" file in CodeIgniter's Core folder:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/tree/develop/system/core

Comment: Ok, thanks for information. But is there a solution for the particular objective:  disable appending slash for first described case?

Comment: That IS the soultion. What do you want, a hand to reach out from their monitor and slap them if they type a slash? You have no control over what the user puts in the url bar, you can only control what is sent back to them..

Comment: I just need to configure Apache to not redirect /module/catalog to /module/catalog/ . As I understand, this can be done only using some htaccess directives (because redirection occures before launching of PHP scripts).

Comment: well, you can certainly make an index.php page which redirects to your original 404 page. i know it's not the solution you were hoping for, but there is a reason all the *real* MVCs do it this way..

Comment: thing is, a good MVC should work just fine with or without an htaccess file. htacess is apache specific. if you want to be able to use it on other systems as well, don't rely on the mod-rewrites. do as much of your redirection as possible in php.